# Need to extract unique values from a column of a table in text file

Tags: windows

I have a table that needs to be handled automatically through a batch file to extract unique values from a particular column. The column number might vary on different execution depending the requirement. It looks like,

```
col1      col2      col3
-----------------------------
Tea.      Red.      Cilo
Tea.      Milk.     Brooks
Coffee    milk.     Shuto
Juice.    Apple.    Dean
Cookies.  Banana.   Cilo
Juice.    Mixed.    Milo
```

Output desired, when applied to col1

```
Tea
Coffee
Juice
Cookies
```

I am quite new to batch scripting. A little explanation of the answer would help a lot.

Answer (score -1):

If the seperator always are whitespaces:
for %%a in (%{YOUR LINE}%) do {do your stuff}

this way you can seperate each word from another and use a loop to check if it is one of your keywords.

Comment: This answer didn't address my query.